# Django1.5, python3, совместимость pil, mysqldb

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте уважаемы коллеги.

Сейчас я изучаю *python* и *django*. Начал свое изучение с **python 3** и **django 1.5.4**. Но не начав работы сразу же столкнулся с неприятностями**. Python 3 не поддерживает MySQLdb и PIL**, но они мне очень нужны. Отсюда вопрос, можно ли на данный момент **преодолеть эти ограничения**, или придется делать шаг назад к python 2.7 ?

*Буду рад любой информации.*

Comment: у нас на проекте (на питоне 3.2) используются SQLAlchemy-0.7.1 и MySql-connector-0.3.2 и полёт нормальный (правда есть небольшие нюансы с миграцией на 3.3 как раз из-за mysql-а), но джанга не изпользуется, может, с ней и есть какие-то нюансы. я бы не стал делать шаг назад -- к тому времени, как нормально научишься, тройка станет еще более распространена.

Comment: [pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.1.0)

Comment: Пока что я склоняюсь все же к третьему питону. Благо что нашел нормальную замену pil для django. Я имею ввиду pillow. Теперь бы найти стабильное решение для mysql, django, python3 и я буду просто счастлив.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы в любом случае посоветовал на python 2.7 перейти. Найдёшь как эти обойти, упрёшься в другие.

P.S. У меня в дистре (думаю и в генту) ветка 3.х вся помечена как нестабильная=) тем более работая с 2.7.х я никаких затруднений не встретил.

P.P.S. [Что нового в Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html)

Comment: Как думаешь как скоро можно будет на python 3 для django переходить?

Comment: @opqx, несколько лет пишу на Python 2.7, и проблем не знаю. В сторону 3 версии даже не смотрел)

Comment: Понятия не имею, через сколько можно будет переходить. Разработчики библиотек не особо спешат переписывать, а основное именно от них зависит. Когда появится достаточное количество библиотек для третьего питона, тогда и можно, но никто дату тебе не назовёт. Тем более второй питон всем устраивает, зачем тебе именно третий?

Comment: Я так понимаю что ветку 2,7 у меня не получиться миновать. Собственно почему python3 ? Просто есть желание писать программы, но я боюсь что когда настрочу тысяч десять строк кода, придется потом переписывать много. Вот это меня немного пугает.

Comment: не думаю. сейчас 2 и 3 ветки сближают по синтаксису. думаю их хотят сделать, если не одинаковыми, то максимально приближенными.

Comment: нашёл инфу, цитирую "Перевести код со второй в третью версию можно скриптами(даются вместе с питоном)". За достоверность не отвечаю.